# Charging 2 li-ion batteries in series

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, series

For my project I need voltage of 2 li-ion batteries in series. For charging them I would use [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/191736124658?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) charger (one for each battery):

Could I connect those two chargers (with one battery on each charger) in series and plug them on 9/12V adapter? Or should I use 5V voltage regulator on each charger?

Another possibility would be to use 7.4V charger like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2S-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-18650-Charger-Protection-Board-Module-3A-7-4V-8-4V-HOT-/322204676503?hash=item4b04e53197:g:uPcAAOSwbsBXlkdh) one.

I would use two identical batteries so I think batteries couldn't get unbalanced.

**EDIT:**

Could I use protection board in second link and a 8.4V adapter like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Universal-DC-8-4V-1A-Output-AC-DC-US-UK-EU-Traveling-Power-Adapter-/221267896928?hash=item3384982a60:g:yyEAAOSwl8NVYu9-) one?

Would 9V adapter be ok?

Comment: Nobody's going to be able to tell without proper data on that charger. So a good recommendation would be : no datasheet, no sale. Consider using a charger designed for a 2S configuration, with charge balancing.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The second link contains a charger protection board for serial li-ion charging. Could I use this board and just plug 9V adapter to charge batteries?

Comment: It wasn't there when I commented.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It wasnt, sorry. But would it work?

Comment: It's not a charger.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, I thougt so. I was googling for battery charger boards that would allso charge batteries, so I could just plug in a 9V/12V adapter. But I couldnt find any. Do you have a recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use 9V/12V and plug chargers in series. You need to use 5V and connect them in parallel.
Imagine that you connect them serially to 10V, and one of batteries is fully charged and the second one fully discharged. Then the first charger won't take any current and the second one will need 1A, it is not going to work, because the first charger will block current and almost whole 10V will be on this charger.

So you have to use that 5V regulator.

**UPDATE:**
Your second link is for 2 cells, so yes, that is better solution than 2 separate chargers.

Comment: Thanks. What about 7.4V charger? I would use identical batteries.

Comment: Is the item in second link even a charger? Or is it just a protection board?

Comment: If the charger lacks a battery balancing feature, it will not be an optimal solution. Better find yourself a balancing charger if you want to charge lithium batteries in series.

Comment: So i couldnt just plug 9V adapter to that board to charge the battery? I think that the board itself has a balancing feauture

Comment: Chargers for cells wired in *series* **cannot be connected in parallel** to the *same* power source.  Fully isolated, independent power sources would be required, and even that is a dubious idea.

Comment: .@ChrisStratto my answer says the same.